# After importing .csv file into textbox. Special characters shows up as "�"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, csv, special-characters

I am trying to import a .csv file exported from google contacts into a textbox in VB.net. For some reason characters such as é å ä ö turns out as � when imported.

This is the code used to import the file:

```
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.CheckFileExists = True
    ofd.CheckPathExists = True
    ofd.Filter = "Text Files|*.csv" 'for multiple filters do this:
    'ofd.Filter = "Text Files, XML Files|*.txt;*.xml"
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(ofd.FileName)
            txtInput.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End If
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the file with the wrong encoding.

Figure out what encoding it really is (probably `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`), then pass the correct `Encoding` instance to whatever method you're using to the `StreamReader` constructor.

Comment: From memory, the quickest way to find out the encoding is to open the file in notepad, select Save As from the menu and you'll see the current encoding of the file in a dropdown box next to the Save button. Ideally you'd get whoever is providing the file to you to always save it in UTF8 format - that way your code will "just work".

Comment: Thx mike that was an easy way to found out the encoding.

Comment: I had the same issue, was using Encoding.UTF8 changing it to Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The .CSV file was encoded with ANSII. Didn't find how to use ANSII while importing so I re-saved the file using UTF-8 so now it works. I'm sure there is a way to do it without having to do it manually like that but this will have to do for now I guess.

Comment: You can pass `Encoding.ASCII` to the `StreamReader` ctor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdStore_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStore.Click
        'InsertDBValues()
     Dim filename As String = "C:\gProducts.csv"
        Dim fields As String()
        Dim delimiter As String = ","
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filename)
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                ' Read in the fields for the current line
                fields = parser.ReadFields()
                ' Add code here to use data in fields variable.
                txtName.Text = fields(1).ToString ' likewise give all textbox 

            End While
        End Using

    End Sub
```